# How to use new Admob with ANT

Tags: android, admob

I'm tryng to setup the new AdMob SDK using instructions on this [Google site](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) for ANT (not gradle).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812511/including-google-admob-sdk-to-use-with-ant) talks about the same problem, but it was asked before google decided to do awat with .jars distribution for Admob and included it in google play services.

I am baffled that the official site does not even talks about ANT configuration at all.

Is there a way to set it up, or do I have to give up and use gradle instead ?

Comment: have u update google-play-services_lib

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Yes I have updated it.

Comment: Some Admob Class are Added In PlayStoreLib in New Sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Ant you are pretty much on your own.

You will need to :

- Unpack the Google Play Services AAR
- Add each of the embedded jars onto your build classpath
- Add each of the embedded jars onto your DEX path

Or you can use Maven or Gradle.

If you are using Maven (my choice) then just add the following dependency to your project. NB you will want to include the android-maven-plugin in your POM too.

https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
    <version>${play-services.verson}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ya I had to upgrade to gradle, any special reason for this hostility towards Ant ?

Comment: It's not hostility. It just economics. Ant was fantastic 15 years ago. But there are more effective tools available now and it more costs to support a range of less effective tools than a few good ones.

Comment: @william is it possible to post detailed instructions similar to example at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en_US but for ant. I hate android studio and gradle. It takes the CPU for a ride for minutes and nothing builds in gradle - its terrible.

Comment: I haven't used Ant in years, I use Maven for all my builds. I'm 100% with re Gradle - it'll probably be good enough in a couple of years, just not now. I've added details for building with Maven above.